# Vue js searching array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to search an array for query string on a json object. The returned fields are an array of filtered results. Currently, the list is returning the name field but not the number field.

```
      computed: {
        search: function () {
          let self = this
          let filtered = []

          filtered = self.jcontacts.filter(function(contact){
            return  contact.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query.toLowerCase())>=0 ||
                    contact.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query.toLowerCase())>=0;
                    contact.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query.toLowerCase()) >=0 ||
                    contact.phonenumber.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query.toLowerCase()) >=0;
            }
          );
          return this.contacts = filtered
        }
      },
    }
```

The filtered method in the search method is not showing the number. An example of the json is below:

> [
>     {
>         "id": 1,
>           "phoneNumber": [
>               "3908902"
>           ],
>           "email": [
>               "jamie@fox.com"
>           ],
>           "firstname": "Jamie",
>           "lastname": "Fox"
>     }]

Comment: your email and phone number are inside array, 
try changing code to `contact.email[0].toLowerCase()` and 
                    `contact.phonenumber[0].toLowerCase()`, this should work

Answer (score 2):

1. Beware of case `phoneNumber != phonenumber`
2. phoneNumber is stored as array not string, so you cant look for it like that (use `.includes()` function for example)
3. For code formatting consider to store `self.query.toLowerCase()` as variable or another computed property

Answer (score 0):

It is a **typo**. Check out field phoneNumber is filtered as phonenumber.

It is an array so you can do it as,

```
contact.phoneNumber.forEach( number => { 
   if(number.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query.toLowerCase()) >=0) 
      return true;
});
```

I think similarly you can write it down for email as well because it is also an array.

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer